Finding a bidisc around the origin contained in a domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$.
I was trying to find a bidisc of the form $D=\{(z_{1}, z_{2}): |z_{1}|<\lambda_{1}, |z_{2}|<\lambda_{2}\}$ which is contained in the domain $\Omega := \{(z_{1} + z_{2}, z_{1}z_{2}): |z_{1}|<1,  |z_{2}|<1\}$.
I have tried a lot but found no explicit form of $D$.
First, I have shown that a bidisc around the origin is guaranteed by the fact that $\Omega$ is open.
However, I am unable to find a precise structure of the bidisc of the form $D$.
Can you please help me find an explicit form of $D$? Thanks in advance.
